# strange characters in DNS Suffix

Tags: dns, ipv4

I have some strange characters in my DNS Suffix. I have removed these strings from registry and attempted to fix this in many other ways. Does anyone here have an idea of what I could do to fix this.

p.s. I saw someone with the same router as me have the same problem [WRT54G].

ipconfig /all printout.

> 

```
C:\Users\gravypod>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : gravypod-PC
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : 5▒c;ì╙ó╪a

Ethernet adapter Hamachi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Hamachi Network Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 7A-79-05-7A-9D-33
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2620:9b::57a:9d33(Preferred)
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::10fb:cf5b:893c:195%16(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 5.122.157.51(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.0.0.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Tuesday, July 17, 2012 7:04:48 PM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Wednesday, July 17, 2013 7:06:55 PM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 5.0.0.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 242907455
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-16-49-AB-D2-00-22-4D-51-8D-66

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) 82579V Gigabit Network Connectio
n
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-22-4D-51-8D-66
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::2d40:a5:9a98:7cde%11(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.109(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Tuesday, July 17, 2012 7:04:48 PM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Wednesday, July 18, 2012 7:04:48 PM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 234889805
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-16-49-AB-D2-00-22-4D-51-8D-66

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 8.8.8.8
                                       8.8.4.4
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.5▒c;ì╙ó╪a:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter 6TO4 Adapter:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft 6to4 Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

Answer (score 0):

Try flushing the DNS the cache, it may be corrupt:

```
Open the Start menu.

Go to Run.

If you do not see the Run command in Vista, search for "run" in the Search bar. 
In the Run text box, type: ipconfig /flushdns

Press Enter or Return, and your cache will be flushed.
```

Comment: I did that, it didnt work

Comment: Try the steps used in this thread: http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=253307 They have the same problem.

Comment: Thats the thread I was talking about @superuser

Comment: If all else fails and you really want to fix it then the only option is to install a custom firmware on the router. It seems to be a firmware bug with the router not your computer. It shouldn't cause any problem if this is left unfixed. If you are willing to install a whole different firmware on the router to fix it, then I would recommend dd-wrt as an alternative to the default Linksys firmware. DD-WRT would allow you to set your own DNS search suffix so it should resolve your issue.